# BigQuery: --[no]use_avro_logical_types flag doesn't work

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to use `bq` command with `--[no]use_avro_logical_types` flag to load avro files into BigQuery table which does not exist before executing the command. The avro schema contains `timestamp-millis` logical type value. When the command is executed, a new table is created but the schema of its column becomes `INTEGER`.
This is a recently released feature so that I cannot find examples and I don't know what I am missing. Could anyone give me a good example?

My avro schema looks like following,

```
...
  }, {
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null,
    "logicalType" : [ "null", "timestamp-millis" ]
  }, {
...
```

And executing command is this:

`bq load --source_format=AVRO --use_avro_logical_types <table> <path/to/file>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the timestamp-millis logical type, you can specify the field in the following way:

```
{
  "name" : "timestamp",
  "type" : {"type": "long", "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"}
}
```

In order to provide an optional 'null' value, you can try out the following spec:

```
{
  "name" : "timestamp",
  "type" : ["null", {"type" : "long", "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"}]
}
```

For a full list of supported Avro logical types please refer to the Avro spec: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Logical+Types.

Comment: The first one that you suggested works! In a case of allowing "null" value, the following schema works instead of your second one. `"type" : [ "null", {"type" : "long", "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"} ]` Thanks!

Comment: Nice correction on the second schema for optional field.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro, the avro type, `timestamp-millis`, is converted to an `INTEGER` once loaded in BigQuery.

Comment: The feature supporting logical type seems to be available now according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894.